# How does one pass command line argument to a ClickOnce application?

Tags: .net, clickonce

I have a Clickonce application that is launched from the start menu (local). I would like to be able to specify a parameter so that the application can load certain data. The application lives on a fileshare and will be launched using the URL only once (like [described here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172242(VS.80).aspx)). This implies that the method describe in this link will not work; users will be launching the application using an .appref-ms shortcut in the Start Menu.

I haven't been able to find a solution. Is it possible to somehow pass a parameter into the click once application? If so, how? If not, what are some alternatives?

Comment: I have a feeling this may get closed due to your other question but what are you trying to solve with arguments to your app?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since you get to the deployment manifest via a Url, you can pass all of that information via the query string (e.g. `http://clickonce.example.com/shell.application?p1=this&p2=that`)

I was going to type out the steps, then googled and found [this blog](http://briannoyes.net/harvesting-clickonce-command-line-arguments/) that basically lists out all the steps.  I've done something similar in one instance with no issues. The only slightly difficult thing is that you have to re-mage after setting things up, but if you got it to deploy in the first place, you already know how to set things up.

Good luck!

Comment: Even though this isn't exactly what I'd like, I think I can make this work.

Comment: I have the same feeling every time I use ClickOnce.  It's so simple to use, but only if you're doing the handful of things it does well.  So, it's just a matter of making sure the tool fits your circumstances.  If you have simple deployment needs, ClickOnce is one of the easiest tools I've ever used

Comment: I tried that blog's solution, but in Windows Explorer, when I Right-Clicked on my "(My App Name).application" File, selected "Created Shortcut", Right-Clicked on that Shortcut File, selected "Properties", changed the "Target" to the above format, selected "Apply" (or "OK") and got a pop-up Window with the message: "Problem with Shortcut The name 'http://(My ClickOnce Publishing Folder Location)/(My App Name).application' specified in the Target box is not valid. Make sure the path and file name are correct.".

Answer (score 6):

All of the answers here only apply to Online ClickOnce applications.  [This MSDN Forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b3360e34-633c-49d8-99c3-8108e557ef47/clickonce-and-command-line-parameters) and [this blog post](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/03/21/how-to-pass-arguments-to-an-offline-clickonce-application/) discuss some ways to do it for Offline ClickOnce applications.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could pass a parameter on the URL the first time, and have the app take notice of that, and write the parameters to a config file, or environment variables or somesuch.

On subsequent runs, load from the config file

Answer (score 0):

You pass the parameters as a query string and use HttpUtility.ParseQueryString, as discussed in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172242.aspx).