# changing or updating app.config at runtime in wpf projects

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wcf, clickonce

How do we overwrite config file at runtime. I have four config files for DEV, TEST, UAT, PROD. Based on user selection I need to overwrite the default config file completely with one of the selection specific config files. These config files not only have appsettings section, but also has complex cutom sections and subelements with lot of attributes. I need to overwrite and refreshsections dynamically at runtime. I know there are so many articles on editing appsettings sections. But I want to completely overwrite the entire file. Your help in VB.net is appreciated.

I have custom sections :

Answer (score 1):

Using ClickOnce, I do not believe you can or should change files within the installation folder because it is read-only... Therefore, you have a choice: go with an MSI install and a custom install action to switch in the appropriate config file **or** build up some custom configuration elements to encapsulate your different environments.

In our application, we have done the latter. We have something like the following custom configuration section in our main app.config.

```
<myApp defaultEnvironmentName="prod">    
  <environments>
    <add name="prod" title="Production" description="Full production environment" injectionContainers="prod">
        ...
        <!-- Add custom elements the affect your environment -->
        ... 
    </add>
    <add name="qa" title="Quality Assurance" description="Full production environment except running off our mock database" injectionContainers="prod qa">
        ...
        <!-- Add custom elements the affect your environment -->
        ... 
    </add>
  </environments>
</myApp>

... <!-- Other elements that are common to all environments --> ...
```

Then we use a [run-time flag or command line argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429351/how-does-one-pass-command-line-argument-to-a-clickonce-application) to enable you to switch between environments easily. The value of the environment in use is stored in a user Settings file so that on subsequent use the application will load the last used environment.

When we need to access something that varies per environment we directly call upon the custom configuration section's `CurrentEnvironment` property which utilised the above mentioned setting to work it out:

```
var title = MyAppSection.Configured.CurrentEnvironment.Title;
```

Note that here, `MyAppSection.Configured` is just a singleton instance that loads based on `ConfigurationManager.GetSection(...)`.

I realise the prospect of a boat-load of configuration code is the last thing you want but it will let you clearly define and isolate your environment variables within the config files.